# Inner classes and parallel class structures

Tags: java, polymorphism, inner-classes

I have an abstract class representing a connector to a data source which returns data objects based on certain criteria. Depending on the source, different subtypes of data objects will be returned, but the clients of this component don't care about and don't need to even know the specific subclasses. Right now, my class structure looks like this (all classes shortened to (hopefully) only display relevant stuff):

```
public abstract class Connector {
    public abstract List<DataObject> getData(Criteria c);

    // some concrete (helper) methods
}

public abstract class DataObject {
    // some concrete methods and properties common to all subtypes

    // some abstract methods to be implemented by subtypes
}

public class ABCConnector extends Connector {
    @Override
    public List<DataObject> getData(Criteria c) {
        // returns List<ABCDataObject>
    }
}

public class ABCDataObject extends DataObject {
    // subtype-specific methods
}
```

In reality, of course there's not only `ABC`, but way more different kinds of Connectors and DataObjects, so that a parallel class structure arises, with two classes belonging together each. Right now, I have the `Connector` and `DataObject` in separate `connectors` and `dataobjects` packages, but I have been thinking about moving the `DataObjects` subtypes into the respective `Connector` subtypes, making them a (static) nested class.

Now, my question is: What are the implications (accessibility, amount of work needed for refactoring, code readability) of such action? Would it be advisable to do so? Would it even be advisable to move the abstract `DataSource` class into the `Connector` class, although the clients need to know about it, as they will work on `List<DataObject>` objects? Is this structure as a whole flawed? If so, how could it be improved?

If you need any further information or this question is better suited for Code Review, please comment.